# Stream API sum & collect into a Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Say you have a map of objects like this (though imagine it being bigger):

`List<Map<String, Object>>`

```
[{
    "rtype": "133",
    "total": 2555
}, {
    "rtype": "133",
    "total": 5553
}, {
    "rtype": "135",
    "total": 100
}]
```

rtype=133, there's two of them!

What I want to do with Streams is this:

```
//result:
//Map<String, Object(or double)>
{"133": 2555+5553, "135": 100} // SUM() of the 133s
```

I have a bit of trouble understanding how Collectors & groupBy stuff works but I imagine that might be used for this case.

What's the proper way to code this in Java streams API?

I'm having trouble finding similar examples with maps (people use lists a lot more in their examples)

Comment: @azurefrog It's a list of maps.

Comment: you have to have at least attempted it and then show us what your struggles are then we can proceed from there.

Comment: Looks like JSON... Would be easier with a POJO

Comment: Yes I'm playing with unit tests .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    e -> e.get("total"), 
    e -> e.get("rtype")));  but summing may require the BinaryOperator part.

Comment: yes I use a lot of JSON different client apps won't always send the right type. It will always be a number followed by decimal points though and not in the billions.

Comment: Why exactly do you need streams? You could easily write this without them

Comment: Point is to learn streams a bit more, it would make for better code and there aren't good examples on the web, isn't that a good idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you really should be using proper classes instead of maps. Having said that, here's how you can group your list of maps:

```
Map<String, Double> grouped = maps.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> (String)m.get("rtype"),
                Collectors.summingDouble(m -> ((Number)m.get("total")).doubleValue())));
```

Comment: See this is the kind of thing I was imagining, I just couldn't figure out the grouping/duplicate part.

Comment: If I make classes instead of maps, then the code won't be generic enough when being passed around between many other methods. I don't think I'd have the time to make a group of classes that could fit all use cases for full OOP.

Comment: +1 for "use proper classes instead of maps."  If your other methods aren't able to handle that, the problem is in your other methods.